# ListView isn't populated with list after setting up binding

Tags: c#, list, listview, windows-phone-8.1, mvvm-light

I've set up two list views in the main page of this application. But the binding using the `grade` and `subject` properties from the VM,  isn't working as expected to display the list of data.

The MVVM light library is being used to aid in following the MVVM pattern in the application, so if the binding needs to be set up differently using that library.

I tried debugging this by checking the following but to no avail:

- Check data context is set up
- Check properties names are correct and correct syntax for binding

Does anyone know why the list data isn't being populated in the ListView during run time?

The model is set up as follows, containing two lists that I need to tie to the list views in the View:

```
namespace LC_Points.ViewModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This class contains properties that the main View can data bind to.
    /// <para>
    /// Use the <strong>mvvminpc</strong> snippet to add bindable properties to this ViewModel.
    /// </para>
    /// <para>
    /// You can also use Blend to data bind with the tool's support.
    /// </para>
    /// <para>
    /// See http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm
    /// </para>
    /// </summary>
    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the MainViewModel class.
        /// </summary>
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            //call methods to initilise list data
            GetGradeTypes();
            GetSubjectTypes();
        }


        private List<Grade> grades { get; set; }
        private List<Grade> subjects { get; set; }


        public void GetGradeTypes()
        {
            List<Grade> gradeList = new List<Grade>();

            // Adding Grades to List
            gradeList.Add(new Grade { grade = "A1" });
            gradeList.Add(new Grade { grade = "A2" });
            gradeList.Add(new Grade { grade = "B1" });
            gradeList.Add(new Grade { grade = "B2" });
            gradeList.Add(new Grade { grade = "B3" });
            gradeList.Add(new Grade { grade = "C1" });
            gradeList.Add(new Grade { grade = "C2" });
            gradeList.Add(new Grade { grade = "C3" });
            gradeList.Add(new Grade { grade = "D1" });
            gradeList.Add(new Grade { grade = "D2" });
            gradeList.Add(new Grade { grade = "D3" });
            gradeList.Add(new Grade { grade = "E,F,NG" });

            grades = gradeList;

        }


        public void GetSubjectTypes()
        {
            List<Grade> subjectList = new List<Grade>();

            // Adding Subjects to List
            subjectList.Add(new Grade { subject = "Accounting" });
            subjectList.Add(new Grade { subject = "Agricultural Economics" });
            subjectList.Add(new Grade { subject = "Agricultural Science" });
            subjectList.Add(new Grade { subject = "Ancient Greek" });
            subjectList.Add(new Grade { subject = "Applied Math" });
            subjectList.Add(new Grade { subject = "Biology" });
            subjectList.Add(new Grade { subject = "Business" });
            subjectList.Add(new Grade { subject = "Business Group" });
            subjectList.Add(new Grade { subject = "Chemistry" });
            subjectList.Add(new Grade { subject = "Classical Studies" });
            subjectList.Add(new Grade { subject = "Engineering" });
            subjectList.Add(new Grade { subject = "English" });

            subjects = subjectList;

        }

    }
}
```

The static resource Locator is defined as follows in App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
        <vm:ViewModelLocator xmlns:vm="using:LC_Points.ViewModel" x:Key="Locator" />
    </Application.Resources>
```

This is the View with the two list views:

```
<Page x:Class="LC_Points.MainPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:local="using:LC_Points"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
      DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator},
                            Path=MainViewModel}"
      mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="90*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="10*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ListView x:Name="subjectOneLbx"
                  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                  Width="211"
                  Height="48"
                  Margin="10,159,0,368.833"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding subjects}" />

        <ListView x:Name="gradeOneLbx"
                  Grid.Column="1"
                  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                  Width="49"
                  Height="48"
                  Margin="132.667,159,0,368.833"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding grades}" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

And this is the data Model for the App:

```
namespace LC_Points.Model
{
    public class Grade : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        // The name of the subject.
        public string subject { get; set; }

        // The type of Grade, eg, A, B2 etc..
        public string grade { get; set; }

        // The points paired with each grade type.
        public int points { get; set; }


        private int _count;
        public int Count
        {
            get
            {
                return _count;
            }
            set
            {
                _count = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Count");
            }
        }





        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }


    }
}
```

The project source tree is structured as follows:

[image: Source Tree]

Comment: How have did you defined the static resource "Locator"?

Comment: Just added that to my question above ^^ , I added it to my app.xaml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used the mvvm-light class before and so I can't comment on that. However, consider these alterations to App.xaml.

---

Case 1: Change App.xaml to this and alter the namespace in MainViewModel:

```
<Application
    x:Class="LC_Points.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:LC_Points">

    <Application.Resources>
        <local:MainViewModel x:Key="Locator"/>
    </Application.Resources>

</Application>
```

MainViewModel.cs:

```
namespace LC_Points
{
    /// <summary>
    /// ...
    /// </summary>
    public class MainViewModel
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// ...
        /// Initializes a new instance of the MainViewModel class.
        /// </summary>
        public MainViewModel()
```

---

Case 2: Leave MainViewModel as is, and change App.xaml

```
<Application
    x:Class="LC_Points.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:LC_Points.ViewModel">

    <Application.Resources>
        <local:MainViewModel x:Key="Locator"/>
    </Application.Resources>

</Application>
```

---

With the orignal xaml that you have, the content will barely show and since you've not provided a datatemplate, you'll get LC_Points.Model.Grade for each entry in grades and subjects. So, I changed it to this (may not be what you want, just for illustration):

```
<Page
    x:Class="LC_Points.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:LC_Points"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="90*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="10*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ListView x:Name="subjectOneLbx" Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding subjects}" SelectionMode="None">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding subject}" Margin="5"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

        <ListView x:Name="gradeOneLbx" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding grades}" SelectionMode="None">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding grade}" Margin="5"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

And I obtained the following result
[image: Image showing result]

Comment: That seems to have fixed the VM path issue, but the contents of the list shows like this, http://picpaste.com/wp_ss_20150506_0002_1_-RvbeaT6P.png  , any idea how I can get the combo box items to be output instead of the name of the property? This is the current VM, https://gist.github.com/BrianJVarley/956633d3a1d4c0437dc9 and the View, https://gist.github.com/BrianJVarley/85bb86b3c0497438f9b9

Comment: You need to use a DataTemplate to describe how you want the data to be displayed. See this: https://gist.github.com/frankibem/ad4042b36e782f1be024

Comment: Turns out I just had to set the `DisplayMemberPath`

Answer (score 2):

You need to make bot `grades` and `subjects` to be `public` properties.

Comment: Okay didn't spot that, I've updated the access modifier's on the two properties `grades` and `subjects` to public now. But the lists still don't show on my View when I run the app on a device. Any other ideas why that could be? I've posted my model above also if that would have any bearing on the error.

Comment: I've also added how I've defined Locator in the app.xaml and a screen shot of my source tree for reference.

Answer (score 2):

You have bound the view to the private properties of the model. Data Binding works with public properties only.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743643.aspx#classes):

> The properties you use as binding source properties for a binding must
>   be public properties of your class. Explicitly defined interface
>   properties cannot be accessed for binding purposes, nor can protected,
>   private, internal, or virtual properties that have no base
>   implementation.